# Passing arguments into a callback function

Tags: python, tkinter, trace

I'm currently writing a Python program using Tkinter. In it, I want to trace the text within several entry boxes. Is there anyway I can pass parameters into the callback function that I call within the trace method? For example:

```
def cb(*args, var):
        do something 

some_object.trace("w", cb(var=some_var))
```

when I try this, I get a None Type error, which I'm assuming is because of how I'm attempting to pass in the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the function immediately, and passing its return value as the callback argument, not passing the function as a callback.

Use `lambda` to create a function that calls the function with an extra argument.

```
some_object.trace("w", lambda *args: cb(*args, var=some_var))
```

You can also use `functools.partial` to create a function with some arguments pre-specified.

```
from functools import partial

some_object.trace("w", partial(cb, var=some_var))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! However, now I am getting this error: TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: I think this is coming because I am trying to trace a user's input within an entry box, so it is trying to end the input into the function now too?

Comment: I've updated it so that the lambda passes along the arguments it received.